# Python RESTful client like Guzzle from PHP

Tags: php, python, rest, guzzle

What Python library provides RESTful client interface like:

```
client = Client(
    base_url="http://example.com/api/1/", auth=("user", "password"),
    cookie=cookielib.FileCookieJar('cookie-file'))
result = client.get('group', params={"groupname": "some_group", "expand": "users"})
result.json()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not exactly like that, but you likely want [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

edit: since you want to ommit your base URL, try something like this:

```
base_url = "http://example.com/"
def requests_get(url, *args, **kwargs):
    return requests.get(base_url + url,*args,**kwargs)
```

An alternative solution is to subclass `requests.Session` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51026159/1016216).

Comment: requests is verbose. I can set base_path?

Comment: Just define your own function that calls requests.get. One second, editing my post.