# Python requests: URL base in Session

Tags: python, python-requests

When using a Session, it seems you need to provide the full URL each time, e.g.

```
session = requests.Session()
session.get('http://myserver/getstuff')
session.get('http://myserver/getstuff2')
```

This gets a little tedious. Is there a way to do something like:

```
session = requests.Session(url_base='http://myserver')
session.get('/getstuff')
session.get('/getstuff2')
```

Comment: I switched to `httpx` which supports this and much more in its `httpx.Client` constructor.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**requests_toolbelt.sessions.BaseUrlSession**
https://github.com/requests/toolbelt/blob/f5c86c51e0a01fbc8b3b4e1c286fd5c7cb3aacfa/requests_toolbelt/sessions.py#L6

NOTE: This uses urljoin from standard lib. Beware of urljoin's behavior.

```
In [14]: from urlparse import urljoin

In [15]: urljoin('https://localhost/api', '/resource')
Out[15]: 'https://localhost/resource'

In [16]: urljoin('https://localhost/api', 'resource')
Out[16]: 'https://localhost/resource'

In [17]: urljoin('https://localhost/api/', '/resource')
Out[17]: 'https://localhost/resource'

In [18]: urljoin('https://localhost/api/', 'resource')
Out[18]: 'https://localhost/api/resource'
```

**OR**

```
import requests 
from functools import partial

def PrefixUrlSession(prefix=None):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
     if prefix is None:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
         prefix = ""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
     else:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
         prefix = prefix.rstrip('/') + '/'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

     def new_request(prefix, f, method, url, *args, **kwargs):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
         return f(method, prefix + url, *args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

     s = requests.Session()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
     s.request = partial(new_request, prefix, s.request)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
     return s
```

Comment: I'm sure there is some rationale for removing that `api` piece of the URI, but holy cow, if it weren't early in the morning with a fresh cup of coffee, I'd be stuck on that for a couple hours wondering why my requests call wasn't working.

Comment: In python3 the urlparse modules has been renamed.  You should use `from urllib.parse import urljoin` instead

Comment: `url = urljoin(self.prefix_url.rstrip("/") + "/", url.lstrip("/"))` to avoid `urljoin`'s annoying behavior...

Comment: @vincent It reflects how browsers resolve URLs. "/resource" is an absolute URL, so it ignores the current path. And "/api" looks like a file (as opposed to "/api/", which is assumed to be "/api/index.html" or something), so it doesn't make sense to append "resource" to it.

Answer (score 53):

This feature has been asked on the forums a few times [1](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/133), [2](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/2445), [3](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/2554). The preferred approach as documented [here](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/2554#issuecomment-109341010), is subclassing, as follows:

```
from requests import Session
from urllib.parse import urljoin

class LiveServerSession(Session):
    def __init__(self, base_url=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.base_url = base_url

    def request(self, method, url, *args, **kwargs):
        joined_url = urljoin(self.base_url, url)
        return super().request(method, joined_url, *args, **kwargs)
```

You would use this simply as follows:

```
baseUrl = 'http://api.twitter.com'
with LiveServerSession(baseUrl) as s:
    resp = s.get('/1/statuses/home_timeline.json')
```

Comment: I like this solution, but it's a bit unfortunate that one has to choose between losing typing for all the following 14 arguments, or implementing the method with all those and their types replicated.

Answer (score 16):

You could just subclass `request.Session` and overload its `__init__` and `request` methods like this:

```
# my_requests.py
import requests


class SessionWithUrlBase(requests.Session):
    # In Python 3 you could place `url_base` after `*args`, but not in Python 2.
    def __init__(self, url_base=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SessionWithUrlBase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.url_base = url_base

    def request(self, method, url, **kwargs):
        # Next line of code is here for example purposes only.
        # You really shouldn't just use string concatenation here,
        # take a look at urllib.parse.urljoin instead.
        modified_url = self.url_base + url

        return super(SessionWithUrlBase, self).request(method, modified_url, **kwargs)
```

And then you could use your subclass instead of `requests.Session` in your code:

```
from my_requests import SessionWithUrlBase


session = SessionWithUrlBase(url_base='https://stackoverflow.com/')
session.get('documentation')  # https://stackoverflow.com/documentation
```

Also you could monkey-patch `requests.Session` to avoid modifying existing codebase (this implementation should be 100% compatible), but be sure to do actual patching before any code calls `requests.Session()`:

```
# monkey_patch.py
import requests


class SessionWithUrlBase(requests.Session):
    ...

requests.Session = SessionWithUrlBase
```

And then:

```
# main.py
import requests
import monkey_patch


session = requests.Session()
repr(session)  # <monkey_patch.SessionWithUrlBase object at ...>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with the [`requests-toolbelt`](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package, which enables setting a `base_url` at the `session` level:

```
from requests_toolbelt import sessions

s = sessions.BaseUrlSession(
    base_url='https://example.com/resource/')
r = s.get('sub-resource/', params={'foo': 'bar'})
```

```
>>> print(r.request.url)
https://example.com/resource/sub-resource/?foo=bar
```

see [documentation for `BaseUrlSession`](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sessions.html#requests_toolbelt.sessions.BaseUrlSession).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a built-in way to do this, but you can use wrapper functions to add the functionality you want:

```
from functools import wraps
import inspect
import requests
from requests.compat import urljoin

def _base_url(func, base):
    '''Decorator for adding a base URL to func's url parameter'''

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        argname = 'url'
        argspec = inspect.getargspec(func)

        if argname in kwargs:
            kwargs[argname] = urljoin(base, kwargs[argname])
        else:
            # Find and replace url parameter in positional args. The argspec
            # includes self while args doesn't, so indexes have to be shifted
            # over one
            for i, name in enumerate(argspec[0]):
                if name == argname:
                    args = list(args)
                    args[i-1] = urljoin(base, args[i-1])
                    break

        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

def inject_base_url(func):
    '''Decorator for adding a base URL to all methods that take a url param'''

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        argname = 'base_url'

        if argname in kwargs:
            obj = args[0]

            # Add base_url decorator to all methods that have a url parameter
            for name, method in inspect.getmembers(obj, inspect.ismethod):
                argspec = inspect.getargspec(method.__func__)

                if 'url' in argspec[0]:
                    setattr(obj, name, _base_url(method, kwargs[argname]))

            del kwargs[argname]

        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

# Wrap requests.Session.__init__ so it takes a base_url parameter
setattr(
    requests.Session,
    '__init__',
    inject_base_url(getattr(requests.Session, '__init__'))
)
```

Now you can specify a base URL when you construct a new requests.Session object:

```
s = requests.Session(base_url='http://stackoverflow.com')
s.get('questions')      # http://stackoverflow.com/questions
s.post('documentation') # http://stackoverflow.com/documentation

# With no base_url, you get the default behavior
s = requests.Session()
s.get('http://google.com')
```

Comment: i like this answer, but it works only when base url has no sublevels like because `urljoin` overwrites them with what is provided as url to get and post methods. i needed it in my case, so i replaced `urljoin` call with simple string concatenation

Answer (score 1):

keep it simple and use builtin methods for joining (no '/' suffix hassle):

```
import urllib.parse
session = requests.Session()
session.my_base_url_join = lambda path: urllib.parse.urljoin(str_BASE_URL, path)
# use: session.get(session.my_base_url_join(path='/message'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @qrtLs answer, here is a 3-4 line version that does what you want (assuming you don't need to create multiple sessions and only need the `get` method defined).

```
import requests
import urllib.parse

session = requests.Session()
session.base_url = "https://google.com/"
session.get = lambda *args, **kwargs: requests.Session.get(session, urllib.parse.urljoin(s.base_url, args[0]), *args[1:], **kwargs)

r = session.get("/search?q=asdf", verify=False)
```