# Hub Connection is not invoking method to server using SignalR in Python

Tags: python, python-requests, signalr-hub

I'm trying to establish a **hub connection** and negotiate through an API provided by a stock exchange company. This is the piece of code developed using the **Signalr_aio** in **Python**.

```
from signalr_aio import Connection
import asyncio
from requests import Session

async def pushMessage(**msg):
    print(msg)
    if 'R' in msg and type(msg['R']) is not bool:
        token = msg['R']
        sessionRealtime.headers.update({'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(token)})

server_url = 'https://edbi.ephoenix.ir/realtime'
sessionRealtime = Session()
connection = Connection(server_url, session=sessionRealtime)
connection.received += pushMessage
hub = connection.register_hub('omsclienttokenhub')
hub.server.invoke('GetAPIToken', 'xxxxxxxxx', 'yyyyyyyyyy')
hub = connection.register_hub('omsclienthub')
connection.start()
```

I tried the 'GetTime' method and it did successfully returned the time,

```
hub.server.invoke('GetTime')
```

> {'R': '00:19:10', 'I': '2'}

However, I get an error when I invoke the 'GetInstrumentList' method,

```
hub.server.invoke('GetInstrumentList')
```

> {'R': {'ex': {'i': None, 'm': 'Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.'}}, 'I': '1'}

I guess that there is a problem in updating the header of the request? Or should I transport the token as a querystring in a modified URL?!

Comment: I'd transport the token as a query string in a modified url.

Comment: Tkanks @gnahum. Do you have any idea what the string format should look like?

Comment: something along the lines of "https://edbi.ephoneix.ir/realtime?token=abc1234"

Comment: Tkanks @gnahum. How do you do that with requests and session?

Comment: with requests you can do something similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42601812/python-requests-url-base-in-session

Comment: instead of sessionRealtime.headers.update({'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(token)})   try this
sessionRealtime.auth = ('token', token)

Comment: Dear @gnahum. Unfortunately, it's not working. I tested both this option and other options of **requests** methods.

Comment: Thanks @NandanRana. This is a SignalR Hub connection. I passed user and pass through the following line:
hub.server.invoke('GetAPIToken', 'user', 'pass')

Comment: is it working now ?

Comment: Dear @NandanRana. I tested sessionRealtime.auth = ('token', token). Unfortunately, it is either not working.

Comment: Did you went through https://edbi.ephoenix.ir/realtime integration doc. How they are expecting token in body or in header of the request? instead of token are they expecting any other value as parameter name ?

Comment: The docs say that the Token should be sent in a QueryString.

Answer (score 1):

Try out below code

```
from requests import Session
from signalr import Connection
import asyncio

server_url = 'https://edbi.ephoenix.ir/realtime'

async def pushMessage(**msg):
    print(msg)
    if 'R' in msg and type(msg['R']) is not bool:
        token = msg['R']
        global server_url
        server_url = 'https://edbi.ephoenix.ir/realtime' +  "?Token={}".format(token)

with Session() as session:
    #create a connection  
    connection = Connection(server_url, session)
    connection.received += pushMessage
    hub = connection.register_hub('omsclienttokenhub')
    hub.server.invoke('GetAPIToken', 'xxxxxxxxx', 'yyyyyyyyyy')
    hub = connection.register_hub('omsclienthub')
    connection.start()
```

I had taken some reference from this [link](https://pypi.org/project/signalr-client/)

Comment: I cannot put connection = Connection(server_url + "?Token={}".format(token), session) at  that line since the token is released after registering the connection connection.register_hub('omsclienttokenhub').

Comment: Another issue is that the token is retrieved in a serialized fashion through an **async** procedure. That's why I defined the function **async def pushMessage(**msg)**.

Comment: Yes.
{'R': {'ex': {'i': None, 'm': 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'}}, 'I': '1'}