# Python make a POST request after the connection is already established

Tags: python, rest, http, post, get

Earlier I a question asking how to create a connection before calling POST, GET etc using the Python Requests library:

[Create connection using Python Request library before calling post/get etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76426442/create-connection-using-python-request-library-before-calling-post-get-etc?noredirect=1#comment134763838_76426442)

turns out I couldn't.

I'm now using the httpclient library and have this:

```
import http.client as httplib

params = my_params()
headers = {"Connection": "Keep-Alive"}

conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("api.domain.com:443")

conn.request("POST", "/api/service", params, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
```

I was hoping it would establish the connection first. However, the line:

```
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("api.domain.com:443")
```

is only taking 2ms to complete and I know the latency to the recipient is approximately 95ms. So, I presume this line isn't creating the connection and it's still being created along with the POST.

How can I make a POST request in Python, where the connection is already established before make the POST request?

Something like:

```
conn = https.connect("api.domain.com:443")
# Connection established before making POST
conn.request("POST", "/api/service", params, headers)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in http.client library, the connection is established when you make the request using the `request()` method. The line `conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("api.domain.com:443")` creates the connection object but doesn't establish the actual connection.

If you want to establish the connection before making the request, you can use the `connect()` method.

Like this:

```py
import http.client as httplib

params = my_params()
headers = {"Connection": "Keep-Alive"}

conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("api.domain.com:443")
conn.connect()

conn.request("POST", "/api/service", params, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()

conn.close()
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPConnection.connect